# How do I change the text of an element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have a *span*, say:

```
<span id="myspan"> hereismytext </span>
```

How do I use JavaScript to change "hereismytext" to "newtext"?

Answer (score 883, accepted):

For modern browsers you should use:

```
document.getElementById("myspan").textContent="newtext";
```

While older browsers may not know `textContent`, it is not recommended to use `innerHTML` as it introduces an XSS vulnerability when the new text is user input (see other answers below for a more detailed discussion):

```
//POSSIBLY INSECURE IF NEWTEXT BECOMES A VARIABLE!!
document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML="newtext";
```

Comment: how do you insert a style attribute into the `span` using javascript here?

Comment: @bouncingHippo document.getElementById("myspan").setAttribute("style","cssvalues");

Comment: @Gregoire keep in mind that your solution doesn't work on ie8 at least. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119300/setattribute-is-not-working-for-style-attribute-on-ie?lq=1

Comment: there should be some way of merging those two answers into one. its the exact same answer.

Comment: This doesn't set the **text**, it sets the **HTML** which is fundamentally different.

Comment: @gregoire - As others have pointed out already your answer is vulnerable to XSS. This question has been viewed about 80k times already, which means that a lot of people have probably taken over this solution and might have introduced unnecessary xss leaks. Could you consider updating your answer to use `textContent` instead, such that new people will be encouraged to use proper and secure methods?

Comment: @Tiddo textContent is not supported in IE8 and below and I hope for you that you never use directly non sanitized user input in your script.

Comment: **Tip:** It doesn't hurt taking a look at the following blog entry: [The poor, misunderstood innerText](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/)  

Great article to get an idea about the differences between `.innerText` and `.textContent`, the performance and also what kinda happens 'behind the scenes'. Some important information is there, IMO. :)

Answer (score 95):

Using *innerHTML* is **SO NOT RECOMMENDED**.
Instead, you should create a textNode. This way, you are "binding" your text and you are not, at least in this case, vulnerable to an XSS attack.

```
document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML = "sometext"; //INSECURE!!
```

The right way:

```
span = document.getElementById("myspan");
txt = document.createTextNode("your cool text");
span.appendChild(txt);
```

For more information about this vulnerability:
[Cross Site Scripting (XSS) - OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

Edited nov 4th 2017:

Modified third line of code according to [@mumush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2460883/mumush) suggestion: "use appendChild(); instead".

Btw, according to [@Jimbo Jonny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1293622/jimbo-jonny) I think everything should be treated as user input by applying Security by layers principle. That way you won't encounter any surprises.

Comment: While you are absolutely correct about `innerHTML` requiring caution, note that your solution uses `innerText` which is not supported in Firefox. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html/ It also uses `textContent` which is not supported in IE8. You can structure code to get around these issues.

Comment: Use `span.appendChild(txt);` instead!

Comment: The question says nothing about user input, so a blanket statement that `innerHTML` is not recommended is ridiculous. Not to mention it is still fine once sanitized. The idea that one should sanitize user input is **SO NOT RELATED** to this specific question. At most it merits a small note at the end saying _"btw: if it's user input make sure to sanitize first or use X method that doesn't need it"_.

Comment: Plus, creating elements is WAY faster than using innerHTML.

Comment: Using appendChild does not actually _change_ the text, it only adds to it.  Using your code here, the span from the original question would end up reading "hereismytextyour cool text". Perhaps `span.innerHTML = "";` then appendChild?

Comment: @JimboJonny When speaking about questions such as this which have been viewed over 650,000 times, what the OP is specifically asking is utterly irrelevant. Therefore I do believe it is prudent to mention the XSS vulnerability prominently, in the interest of public safety.

Answer (score 42):

**EDIT:** This was written in 2014. A lot has changed. You probably don't care about IE8 anymore. And Firefox now supports `innerText`.

If you are the one supplying the text and no part of the text is supplied by the user (or some other source that you don't control), then setting `innerHTML` might be acceptable:

```
// * Fine for hardcoded text strings like this one or strings you otherwise 
//   control.
// * Not OK for user-supplied input or strings you don't control unless
//   you know what you are doing and have sanitized the string first.
document.getElementById('myspan').innerHTML = 'newtext';
```

However, as others note, if you are not the source for any part of the text string, using `innerHTML` can subject you to content injection attacks like XSS if you're not careful to properly sanitize the text first.

If you are using input from the user, here is one way to do it securely while also maintaining cross-browser compatibility:

```
var span = document.getElementById('myspan');
span.innerText = span.textContent = 'newtext';
```

Firefox doesn't support `innerText` and IE8 doesn't support `textContent` so you need to use both if you want to maintain cross-browser compatibility.

And if you want to avoid reflows (caused by `innerText`) where possible:

```
var span = document.getElementById('myspan');
if ('textContent' in span) {
    span.textContent = 'newtext';
} else {
    span.innerText = 'newtext';
}
```

Comment: 2022 Update: For the people who might come across this answer, now `innerText` is supported in Firefox [see the Caniuse status](https://caniuse.com/innertext). So you can only use `innerText`. And also [check the MDM doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) to see the differences between `innerText` and `textContent`.

Comment: @BenSouchet Thanks. I've updated the caveat that starts the answer to include the Firefox info. Feel free to edit further if you think it would be helpful to provide additional info and/or links to folks.

Answer (score 31):

```
document.getElementById('myspan').innerHTML = 'newtext';
```

Comment: If `'newtext'` contains user-supplied input, this will lead to XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 26):

I use `Jquery` and none of the above helped, I don't know why but this worked:

```
 $("#span_id").text("new_value");
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's another way:

```
var myspan = document.getElementById('myspan');

if (myspan.innerText) {
    myspan.innerText = "newtext";
}
else
if (myspan.textContent) {
        myspan.textContent = "newtext";   
}
```

The innerText property will be detected by Safari, Google Chrome and MSIE.  For Firefox, the standard way of doing things was to use textContent but since version 45 it too has an innerText property, as someone kindly apprised me recently. This solution tests to see if a browser supports either of these properties and if so, assigns the "newtext".

Live demo: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/duy8zvmm/1/)

Comment: Firefox implemented innerText support in [release 45](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/45).

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the pure javascript answers above, You can use jQuery *text* method as following:

```
$('#myspan').text('newtext');
```

If you need to extend the answer to get/change *html* content of a span or div elements, you can do this:

```
$('#mydiv').html('<strong>new text</strong>');
```

**References:**

.text(): http://api.jquery.com/text/

.html(): http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 6):

Many people still come across this question (in 2022) and the available answers are not really up to date.

## Use `innerText` is the best method

As you can see in the [MDM Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) `innerText` is the best way to retrieve and change the text of a `<span>` HTML element via Javascript.

The `innerText` property is VERY well supported (**97.53%** of all web users [according to Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/innertext))

### How to use

Simple retrieve and set new text with the property like this:

```js
let mySpan = document.getElementById("myspan");

console.log(mySpan.innerText);

mySpan.innerText = "Setting a new text content into the span element.";
```

### Why better than `innerHTML` ?

Don't use `innerHTML` to updating the content with user inputs, this can lead to major vulnerability since the string content you will set will be interpreted and converted into HTML tags.

This means users can insert script(s) into your site, this is known as XSS attacks/vulnerabilities (Cross-site scripting).

### Why better than `textContent` ?

First point `textContent` isn't supported by IE8 (but I think in 2022 nobody cares anymore).
But the main element is the true difference of result you can get using `textContent` instead of `innerText`.

The [example from the MDM documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText#example) is **perfect** to illustrate that, so we have the following setup:

```html
<p id="source">
  <style>#source { color: red;  } #text { text-transform: uppercase; }</style>
<span id=text>Take a look at<br>how this text<br>is interpreted
       below.</span>
  <span style="display:none">HIDDEN TEXT</span>
</p>
```

If you use `innerText` to retrieve the text content of `<p id="source">` we get:

```
TAKE A LOOK AT
HOW THIS TEXT
IS INTERPRETED BELOW.
```

This is perfectly what we wanted.

Now using `textContent` we get:

```
  #source { color: red;  } #text { text-transform: uppercase; }
Take a look athow this textis interpreted
       below.
  HIDDEN TEXT
```

Not exactly what you expected...

This is why using `textContent` isn't the correct way.

### Last point

If you goal is only to append text to a `<p>` or `<span>` HTML element, [the answer from nicooo.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25273968/10797718) is right you can create a new text node and append it to you existing element like this:

```js
let mySpan = document.getElementById("myspan");

const newTextNode = document.createTextNode("Youhou!"),

mySpan.appendChild(newTextNode);
```

Answer (score 3):

You may also use the querySelector() method, assuming the 'myspan' id is unique as the method returns the first element with the specified selector:

```
document.querySelector('#myspan').textContent = 'newtext';
```

[developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Answer (score 2):

Like in other answer, *innerHTML* and *innerText* are not recommended, it's better use ***textContent***. This attribute is well supported, you can check it this:
    http://caniuse.com/#search=textContent

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("myspan").textContent="newtext";
```

this will select dom-node with id `myspan` and change it text content to `new text`

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
 document.querySelector("[Span]").textContent = "content_to_display";
```

Comment: what is the difference with the answer I gave?

Answer (score 1):

Can't be used with HTML code insertion, something like:
`var a = "get the file <a href='url'>the link</a>"`
`var b = "get the file <a href='url'>another link</a>"`
`var c = "get the file <a href='url'>last link</a>"`

using
`document.getElementById("myspan").textContent=a;`
on
`<span id="myspan">first text</span>`

with a timer but it just shows the reference target as text not runing the code, even tho it does shows correctly on the source code. If the jquery approch is not really a solution, the use of:

`document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML = a to c;`
is the best way to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const span = document.querySelector("#span");
const btn = document.querySelector("#changeBtn");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
span.innerText = "text changed"
})
```

```html
<span id="span">Sample Text</span>
<button id="changeBtn">Change Text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this span

```
<span id="name">sdfsdf</span>
```

You can go like this :-

```
$("name").firstChild.nodeValue = "Hello" + "World";
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myspan").text("This is span");
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="myspan"> hereismytext </span>
```

user `text()` to change span text.

Answer (score 0):

I used this one `document.querySelector('ElementClass').innerText = 'newtext';`

Appears to work with span, texts within classes/buttons

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it seems that using "text" attribute is the way to go with most browsers.
It worked for me

$("#span_id").text("text value to assign");

Comment: Same solution already suggested by Mohamed Nagieb and Rayees AC.

Comment: This use jQuery instead of pure javascript