# setAttribute is not working for 'style' attribute on IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm porting a piece of JS code written for Firefox into Internet Explorer. I faced a problem of changing style of an element using `setAttribute` method which was working on Firefox.

```
button.setAttribute('style', 'float: right;');
```

I tried setting the style member of button and it didn't work either. This was the solution in case of setting `onclick` event handler.

```
button.style = 'float: right;';
```

First I wanna know the solution for the above problem and
Second are there any maintained lists for these differences between browsers ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but differences like this are the biggest "pro" point for using a framework like JQuery, Prototype, MooTools or Dojo. Porting JS becomes 95-99% unnecessary with those.

Comment: Seems this was broken in IE at some point. You should be able use button.setAttribute('style', '') since this method is only responsible for setting the attributes values. The fact that button.style is an object is just another way of setting that same attribute. It seems to be working in IE11 as of this comment.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Because style itself is an object. What you want is:

```
button.style.setAttribute('cssFloat','right');
```

But IE doesn't support setAttribute for style objects. So use the fully cross-browser supported:

```
button.style.cssFloat = 'right';
```

As for reference, I always go to www.quirksmode.org . Specifically: http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html . Click on all the DOM related stuff.

And finally, to set multiple attributes I usually use something like:

```
function setStyle(el,spec) {
    for (var n in spec) {
        el.style[n] = spec[n];
    }
}
```

usage:

```
setStyle(button,{
    cssFloat : 'right',
    border : '2px solid black'
});
```

Note: `object.attribute = 'value'` although works in all browsers may not always work for non-HTML DOM objects. For example, if your document contains embedded SVG graphics that you need to manipulate with javascript you need to use `setAttribute` to do it.

Comment: "Because style itself is an object" is only half the story and "button.style.setAttribute" will throw an error because the style object doesn't have a setAttribute method.

Comment: Are there any ways, I can add multiple semicolon separated styles without setting each individual attribute ?

Comment: `button.style.float = 'right'` will also break. There is no float property because float is a reserved keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: Fixed bugs. Thanks for catching them David :-)

Comment: `button.style.setAttribute('float','right');` is still going to error.

Comment: No, it isn't. There is no setAttribute method on the style property!

Comment: And your multiple setting script is broken too! `foo.n` references the property `n` not the property with the same name as the value of the variable `n`.

Comment: It also fails follow the best practice of testing hasOwnProperty inside a for loop.

Comment: This worked for me in IE7,8,9 and 10. Not sure what the above nay-sayers are on about

Comment: I'll comment that IE doesn't like properties with a dash (-) so use array syntax with these properties like: div.style["z-index"] = "100";

Comment: @MikeCheel: That won't normally work at the time I wrote this answer. Maybe it works now but I doubt it. In javascript the proper name for `z-index` is `zIndex`. For every css attribute that contain `-` there is an equivalent style property in camelCase. So `zIndex`, `backgroundImage`, `fontSize` etc.

Comment: @MikeCheel: That's not all. Notice also that the `style` property does not have a `float` property so you cannot do `style.float = 'right'`. Instead it has `cssFloat`. You need to refer to the w3c spec or MDN docs or MSDN docs for the correct name.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use cssText

```
 button.style.cssText = 'float: right;';
```

Answer (score 6):

`getAttribute` and `setAttribute` are broken in Internet Explorer.

The correct syntax for what you are trying to achieve is:

```
button.style.cssFloat = 'right';
```

The correct solution to the problem is more likely to be:

```
button.className = 'a class that matches a pre-written CSS rule-set';
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that setAttribute works in IE only when the attribute does not already exist.
Therefore, use remove attribute and then use set attribute.

Haven't tested this for bugs, but conceptually I think this will work:

**NOTE** - this was written to exist inside object that had property called 'element'.

```
//Set Property

this.setProperty = function (a, b) {
var c = this.element.getAttribute("style");
var d;
if (!c) {
    this.element.setAttribute("style", a + ":" + b);
return;
} else {
    d = c.split(";")
}

for (var e = 0; e < d.length; e++) {
    var f = d[e].split(":");
    if (f[0].toLowerCase().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").indexOf(a.toLowerCase().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")) == 0) {
       d[e] = a + ":" + b
    }
}

d[d.length] = a + ":" + b;
this.element.setAttribute("style", d.join(";"))
}

//Remove Property
this.removeProperty = function (a) {
var b = this.element.getAttribute("style");
var c;
if (!b) {
    return
} else {
    c = b.split(";")
}

for (var d = 0; d < c.length; d++) {
    var e = c[d].split(":");
    if (e[0].toLowerCase().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").indexOf(a.toLowerCase().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")) == 0) {
        c[d] = ""
    }
}

this.element.removeAttribute("style");
this.element.setAttribute("style", c.join(";").replace(";;", ";"))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another useful way to mutate a style property is using the square brackets to access the property. This is useful for accessing properties which because of their name would give a syntax error if expressed normally. In JavaScript it is perfectly permissible to have properties with numeric values, numeric first letters and symbols and spaces as characters, but then you must use the square bracket way of accessing properties.

```
node.style.z-index = 50;//Firefox says error, invalid assignment left hand side.

node.style["z-index"] = "50";//Works without error
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work in IE. Just tried it out.

1. The method is passed a style name and a value
2. The method then checks to see if there are any styles
   If no styles attribute exists, then the method simply sets the style and stops
3. If a style attribute exists, all the styles in the attribute are split into an array
4. The array is iterated and all applicable style definitions are updated with the new value
5. The style attribute is then removed from the element
6. The style attribute is added back to the element with its values set to the new info
   gathered from the array