# Get child element by HTML Object

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I'm attempting to reuse the variable "startGame", variable through which I declare an "a" element to be appended to the "table" element, in order to test for its own presence posteriorly. The code I've written for doing so is the following:

```
//Helper function to set HTML Tags attributes
function setAttributes(element, attributes)
{ for (var key in attributes) { element.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]); } }

//Opening screen
var startGame = document.createElement("a");
setAttributes(startGame,
{
    "style" : "float:left; width: 100%; text-align: center;",
    "onclick" : "dealHands()"
});
startGame.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Play"));

var table = document.getElementById("table");
table.appendChild(startGame);

function dealHands()
{
    if (table.childNodes[0].nodeValue == startGame)
    { table.removeChild(startGame); }
    ...
}
```

So far, the code fails to perceive "startGame" and nothing happens.

Comment: Is the element with the ID `"table"` actually a `<table>` element? If so, that'll be part of the problem. Please include your `HTML` in the question.

Comment: What errors appear in your browser's console?

Comment: BTW Nice word **posteriorly** ;)

Comment: @Crazy Train: Nope, Its a div. Actually I've already solved the problem, but I can't answer my own question because I don't have enough "reputation". I just had to remove the ".nodeValue" from the if statement in order to make a comparison between two HTML elements instead of comparing a value with a HTML element.

Andy G: Thanks. Actually, in portuguese "posteriormente" isn't uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the style attributes using this:

```
"style" : "float:left; width: 100%; text-align: center;"
```

they have to be set individually. But IE doesn't support changing `style` in this way. You need:

```
element.style.cssFloat = "left";    // etc.
```

[Discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119300/setattribute-is-not-working-for-style-attribute-on-ie)

Also, I wouldn't use `table` as an ID.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've changed my code for IE compliance.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to remove the ".nodeValue" from the if statement in order to make a comparison between two HTML elements instead of comparing a value with a HTML element.