# Joomla - Object doesn't support this property or method in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

When viewing a site in IE8 (with Browser Mode: IE8 Compatibility Mode and Document Mode: IE7 Standards on) I'm getting the following error:

```
    Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
    Line: 6
    Char: 2
    Code: 0
    URI:        http://newsite.hutspace.co.uk/modules/mod_jlnewsslider/assest/_class.noobSlide.packed.js
```

This is Line 6 in the above file:

```
this.box=a.box.setStyle(this.modes[this.mode][1],(this.size*this.items.length)+'px');
```

Any ideas what's wrong? The error doesn't show up in Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe cache problem.

Check this answer: [LINK](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method/bb8b8be5-270c-44fd-a692-8e55d8ce499b)

But this is probably SetStyle method problem.
Try to write your own function for this.

Check this answer also: [SetStyle IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119300/setattribute-is-not-working-for-style-attribute-on-ie)