# How to capture a value not through an input field in a form using php and mysql ?

Tags: forms, html, form-submit

Hello everybody and good day ,

I am making a web application in php and mysql

Iam trying to make a page where a user can create a custom form eg. User can create custom forms so they can type the name of the input, however the place where they type the name of the input i have it formated like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
 <span spellcheck="false" id="a">Editable Content</span><em>o!</em>
</div>
```

so its not an input field .

How can i capture this information in a form , maybee with a hidden input field, a label or with jquery ?

if my question is not clear let me know i will edit ti it as soon as i get a chance .

Comment: Although this should be possible creating a new 'form' element inside the document, I don't understand why you should use spans instead of inputs... Is there a special reason for that?

Comment: Yes there is : its mainly for styling purpouses , this way it looks like normal text otherwise i would have to have an input field

Comment: What about styling with CSS? Just created: http://jsfiddle.net/ujLAV/

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to collect the text inside the span.

This question is related [How do I change the text of a span element in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-in-javascript)

The answers mention document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML which is the place that text resides. You'll want to change the "myspan" though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either a form or send the data with AJAX.

```
document.getElementById("your-form").onsubmit = function()
{
  var spanInput = document.createElement("input");
  spanInput.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  spanInput.setAttribute("name", "spanData");
  spanInput.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById("a").innerHTML);

  this.appendChild(spanInput);

  return true;
}

// or
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){} // please change
xhr.open("POST", "your-script.php");
var spanData = document.getElementById("a").innerHTML;
xhr.send("spanData="+encodeURIComponent(spanData));
```