# Change span text?

Tags: javascript, text, edit, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the text of a span element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-in-javascript)

Well, I've searched a lot for the answer to this, but still I couldn't find it. What I did find didn't work.

What I'm trying to do is, basically, using JavaScript: At the browser's bar, not via Greasemonkey or something else, edit a span's text .

This' the span that contains the text I want to edit:

```
<span id="serverTime">5:46:40</span>
```

The time within is just random, don't pay attention to it, it's what I want to edit using javascript..

I'm a newbie so yeah :\

Answer (score 151, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("serverTime").innerHTML = ...;
```

Comment: I  tried it but it just opens a window with a white background and has the text I've entered..

Comment: In a bookmarklet, you need to add `void(...)` around it to suppress its return value.

Comment: What's the need for it to be done via address bar? You could likely emulate the function it would have when used in the address bar with on-page javascript.

Comment: so it'd be javascript:void(document.getElementById("serverTime").innerHTML = ...); ?

Answer (score 8):

Replace whatever is in the address bar with this:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('serverTime').innerHTML='[text here]';
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/QuNN6/).

Comment: I tried it but it just opens a window with a white background and has the text I've entered..

Comment: It worked for me: **<button id="btnTest" onclick="document.getElementById('title').innerHTML='text here';" type="button">TEST</button>**