# Automatically Create New Pages in Firebase Hosting on user events(JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting

I'm creating a blog Website project using Firebase.

What I want is - Create an entirely new Page for the Blog Posts once a USER creates it.

FOR EXAMPLE -

- If a user submits a post with the title: **"Best Watches in 2019"**.
- then it should create a new page like: **"blog.com/best-watches-in-2019.html"**

I searched the web a lot about this, but I'm still a beginner in Firebase. Please help me with a solution guys, or a workaround if it's not directly possible.

Comment: Does it need to be an HTML page? Couldn't it be a record in a database, e.g. Firestore, that can be fetched by a specific page when opened, e.g. `blog.com/page?contentId=AZERTYUIOP`  (`AZERTYUIOP` being the id of the database record/Firebase doc).

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Can you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following HTML page shows how you can query the Firestore database when the HTML page is opened, based on a value passed as a query string parameter.

So, you should do as follows:

- Create a collection named `blogPosts` in your Firestore database
- Add a document with, for example, the id `best-watches-in-2019` and a field named `field1` where you enter any string value
- Copy the HTML code below and create an HTML page that you save on your computer.
- Open the page in your brower and add `best-watches-in-2019` as query string parameter as folllows: `http://yourdirectory/yourpagename.html?contentId=best-watches-in-2019`.

---

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <span id="field1"></span>

    <script>
      var config = {
        apiKey: 'xxxx',
        authDomain: 'xxxx',
        projectId: 'xxxx'
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);

      $.extend({
        getUrlVars: function () {
          var vars = [],
            hash;
          var hashes = window.location.href
            .slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1)
            .split('&');
          for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
          }
          return vars;
        },
        getUrlVar: function (name) {
          return $.getUrlVars()[name];
        },
      });

      $(document).ready(function () {
        var documentID = $.getUrlVar('contentId');

        firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection('blogPosts')
          .doc(documentID)
          .get()
          .then(function (doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
              $('#field1').text(doc.data().field1);
            } else {
              // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
              console.log('No such document!');
            }
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error getting document:', error);
          });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, buddy! The problem is, I don't know how to work with jQuery. I'm still a beginner developer. 
I know it's a long code, and I understand that it must have took you a long time to write this for me.
Can you please help me with the JavaScript version of this. I'll be really grateful.

Comment: You should adapt it by applying the techniques detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177215/change-span-text and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks a lot, Relauld, I'm really grateful. Just one more question - Will Search Engines like google view these URLs as different pages?

Comment: Hello Raghav, AFAIK no, search engines will not consider them as different pages since the content is dynamically loaded. If this is a important requirement for you you should adopt another platform or approach, like Wordpress or Server side rendering (e.g. Nuxt.js), etc....