# Counter not visible

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show the countdown inside the span tags(but it's not showing) and how do I stop it from printing number again and again (if it works).

```
<span></span>

<script>
    const countDown = (counter) => {
            const displayer = document.querySelector('span');
            for (counter = 10; counter >= 0; counter--) {
                return displayer.counter
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of inventing your own properties, maybe reading how the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) works helps to create a DOM manipulator.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. DOM elements does not have `.counter`; you do nothing with `countDown`, you never call it. Your loop is stopped automatically when `counter` reaches 0. Maybe do `displayer.innerText = counter`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change span text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177215/change-span-text)

Comment: An unconditional return statement in a loop doesn't make sense. It will always leave the loop after the first iteration.

Comment: Oh, and all you will see is `10`, since loop is synchronous and user will see only last iteration result. And last iteration is 10, because loop returns on first iteration

Answer (score 1):

Looking for something like this?

- `displayer.innerText = counter;` to update the text of the element.
- Make a delay inside the loop, otherwise you will not see the change 10,9,8...0 because the loops runs in microseconds to it's end

```js
const delay = (time) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, time));

const countDown = async (counter) => {
  const displayer = document.querySelector('span');
  for (counter = 10; counter >= 0; counter--) {
    displayer.innerText = counter;
    await delay(1000);
  }
}


countDown(10);
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Comment: https://2ality.com/2018/02/numeric-separators.html Official feature to separate numbers using underscore `1_000 === 1000`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error and explaining it.

Answer (score -1):

This will work so fast and you'll never see 10, 9, 8, ...

1-Problem can be about querySelector() to select correct element

2-You must use setInterval() or setTimeout() methods for these kind applications..

3-you are trying to show counter object inside displayer in return statement, you may use `displayer.innerHTML=counter` to write counter variable inside span element