# Populate table fields based on user input

Tags: javascript, html

I have to make an app, that takes a user input field, and then populates a table, according to some calculations. However, I don't understant how can I do this calculations to appear as a result in the field of the table. Can someone help me please?
Here is my code;

```js
function countbase() {
  let count = 0;

  var input = document.getElementById('sequence').value;


  const inputLen = input.length;
  document.getElementById('bcount').value = GC_Content;
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<h2>Calculater example</h2>

<label for="sequence">  Name field</label>
<br>
<br>
<textarea id="sequence" name="sequence" placeholder="Enter sequence" rows="2" cols="50">
    </textarea>
<br><br>
<button onclick="countbase();">Check </button>
<br><br>

<table style="width:100%" id="values">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">&nbsp;Results</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><span><b>Lenght Count:</b></span></td>
    <td align="center"><span id="bcount"></span></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><span><b>Word Count  :</b></span></td>
    <td><b><span id="GC"></span></b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your line:

```js
document.getElementById('bcount').value = GC_Content;
```

Here `GC_Content` isn't defined, I guess you trying to set the `inputLen` variable.

That said, to change the content of a `<span>`, use `innerHTML`:
[Change span text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177215/change-span-text)

To get the 'word count', we can use [`split(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to create an array of the input string, then set the `.length` of that array as the content of the `<span>`

```js
function countbase(){

  // Get input element
  const input = document.getElementById('sequence').value;
 
  // Set length
  document.getElementById('bcount').innerHTML = input.length;
  
  // Set word count
  document.getElementById('GC').innerHTML = input.split(' ').length;
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<h2>Calculater example</h2>
    
<label for="sequence">  Name field</label>
<br>
<br>
<textarea id="sequence" name="sequence" placeholder= "Enter sequence" rows="2" cols="50">
</textarea>
<br><br>
<button onclick="countbase();">Check </button>  
<br><br>

<table style="width:100%" id="values">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">&nbsp;Results</th>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td align="center"><span><b>Lenght Count:</b></span></td>
        <td align="center"><span id="bcount"></span></td>
        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><span><b>Word Count  :</b></span></td>
        <td><b><span id="GC"></span></b></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help,this works, but what if I want to add more functions, meaning that I want another function that counts vowels? should I add it to the function already created, or can I create another function apart from that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.split()` method and then get length of result array
`let GC_Content = input.split(" ").length` //splits input by spaces and count length of result array

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).