# How to replace text inside IDless <span> with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some text inside `<span></span>` tags and I want to change that text to something else when page is loaded.

So lets say default text is 'Story' (outputted by some CMS system and I can't edit it). So when page is loaded, .js detects that 'Story' word and replaces it with 'View This Story'.

Is that possible somehow?

Cheers

Update: I did search before asking and none of those methods I found works. Like I said the text is outputted by CMS and it gives wrong title, the title itself cannot be edited via CMS because it is used for other terms and tagging which is correct, so I was looking for js workaround to rename it on page load.

And span has no ID and I cannot give it any ID, because like I said it works as designed by CMS.

```
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first active">
  <div class="views-field views-field-name">
    <span class="field-content">Story</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
  <div class="views-field views-field-name">
   <span class="field-content">Second Story</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see spans do not have IDs, but repeating classes only.

Comment: Can you give a sample of your markup? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate. Please do some research before you ask questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the text of a span element in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-in-javascript)

Comment: if you searched before asking, show what you've tried! Questions get better answers when they are backed by a code sample.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't find any answer for my situation. What's with the downvoting?

Comment: @user13176 Your answer is at the bottom of the updated answer from `MelanciaUK` (currently at the top when sorted by votes)

Comment: I also left a comment there. It works only for one span. I am newbie to JS, sorry.

Comment: Fixed and ready to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED as per OP request**

You can replace any text within spans. You could even use regular expressions to make it more flexible, but let's leave this for now:

**Native Javascript**

```
var lookupSpanAndReplace = function(textFrom, textTo) {
   var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

   for (i=0; i<spans.length; i++) 
      if (spans[i].innerHTML.indexOf(textFrom) >= 0)
          spans[i].innerHTML = mySpan.innerHTML.replace(textFrom, textTo);
}

lookupSpanAndReplace("Story", "My New Text");
```

**jQuery**

```
var lookupSpanAndReplace = function(textFrom, textTo) {
    $('span:contains(' + textFrom + ')').each(function(index, element) { 
        $(element).text($(element).text().replace(textFrom, textTo));
    });
}

lookupSpanAndReplace("Story", "My New Text");
```

Comment: `span#mySpanId` is a bad selector - the `span` is redundant. It should just be `#mySpanId`

Comment: Fixed. And I was wrongly assuming the OP wanted to replace the whole text. Now it's taking into consideration the string wanted to be replaced.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Not strictly true.  What if the page were being generated and the element with ID `SpanId` could be something else?  (Okay, it wouldn't be that ID, but you get my drift.)

Comment: @Archer There should never be more than one element with the same ID, therefore the tag name is completely redundant. If this isn't true on a page, it has been developed wrong - simple as.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I know that there shouldn't be more than 1 element with any given ID, but I'm pointing out that there is a legitimate use for `type#ID`.  What if the page were generated and the element could be any number of things, but the ID would always be the same?  There would only be 1 of them, so that's all good.  Say you wanted to style those element types differently - how would you do that?  You can't use ID since it could be any type!  You use `type#ID`.  It's not common, but it is a legitimate use for what you said shouldn't be done :)

Comment: @Archer Right I see what you mean now, but why on earth a system would generate different elements with the same ID is simply baffling. Another bad project design right there. There should never be a need for `tag#id` - if that situation is unavoidable give the element a class depending on use, or use unique ids and a merged css selector e.g. `#infospan,#infodiv`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I agree it's not usual and does sound terrible, but say you had a table and one of the columns was a mixture of inputs and static text.  It would be much easier to refer to the elements by ID, but you'd obviously style them differently.  Also you shouldn't be using classes like IDs, as IDs uniquely identify an element without parsing everything else to find it.  I believe there are legitimate use cases out there - just not many.

Comment: @Archer Let's just agree to disagree - I just can't think of any instance where the situation would be unavoidable. Let's leave poor MelanciaUK's comment section alone.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Absolutely :)

Comment: The Native Javascript without ID tags works fine but only for the first span text. How do I replace the rest of the span texts in the same page with different texts?

Comment: With a little bit of effort, you'd find out. I've updated the answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#spanID').text("View This Story");
```

or if you want to replace a part of text

```
$('#spanID').text(function () {
    return this.innerHTML.replace('Story', 'View This Story');
});
```

Comment: Can I ask why the anonymous function?

Comment: @agrothe if user want to replace a part of text.

Comment: @agrothe In order to do a replace on the text value.

Comment: I know the text replace part, but you don't need an anonymous function to do that. Was just curious why you inserted that. Not sure who downvoted.

Comment: @agrothe How would you do a string replace inside an element?  (This is not the best example as it's totally replacing it, not just part of it.)

Comment: I read that too quickly right after reading @DesertIvy's reply thinking it was doing the same thing. Still possible without but certainly more ugly. Good answer sir.

Answer (score 0):

Give you `span` an ID and then run `text([your new text])` on that node:

**HTML**

```
<span id="mySpan">Story</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#mySpan').text("View This Story");
```

**[JSFiddle with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/MySuh/)**

Or you can do it without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = "View This Story";
```

**[JSFiddle with plain 'ol Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/dVBRm/1/)**

Comment: Wat? The question is also marked as jQuery so what does it matter?

Comment: Uh... he tagged it as [jQuery]. I see no problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function changeSpan(){
   var spans = document.getElementsByTagName ("span");
   for (i = 0; i < spams.length; i++){
      spans[i].innerHTML = textThatYouWant ();
   }
}

</script>

<head onload="changeSpan()" >
   <tile> ... </title>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

Comment: Spam, scam, etc. All bad.

Comment: I wanted to write "span".

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to **solve the issue**.

### HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function replace_text_span()
        {
         for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName('span').length;i++)
         {
          document.getElementsByTagName('span')[i].innerHTML=document.getElementsByTagName('span')[i].innerHTML.replace("Story","View This Story");
         }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="replace_text_span()">
    <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first active">
      <div class="views-field views-field-name">
        <span class="field-content">Story</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
      <div class="views-field views-field-name">
       <span class="field-content">Second Story</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```