# Insert value of object into span tag

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
message: {
    text: "Here is some text"
}
```

I want to insert it into a span tag like this:

```
<span>message.text</span>
```

This won't print 'Here is some text', instead it will just show 'message.text' on the webpage. How can I get it to show the actual contents of the object?

Comment: Are you using any template engine e.g. Jade/Handlebars or plain HTML?

Comment: Use the DOM, select that span element, set its `.textContent` from your script.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give something id to span

```
<span id="span"></span>
$("#span").text(message.text);
```

Comment: This example uses jQuery, which is fine, because jQuery is excellent in manipulating the DOM. However it's a good habit to learn how JavaScript works behind the library/framework.

Answer (score 2):

**With Plain JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('text-holder')[0].textContent = message.text;
```

```js
var message = {
    text: 'Here is some text'
};
document.getElementsByClassName('text-holder')[0].textContent = message.text;
```

```html
<span class="text-holder"></span>
```

**With jQuery:**

```js
var message = {
  text: 'Here is some text'
};

$('.text-holder').text(message.text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="text-holder"></span>
```

**With AngularJS:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = {
    text: 'Here is some text'
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <span>{{message.text}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer including also the use of popular libraries and frameworks. I would upvote it, if there wasn't a critical typo: `getElementByTagName`. There is no such thing in JS. Did you mean: `getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: Sorry, I found another typo: Angula**ge**JS

Comment: @cezar yes please? which one?

Comment: @cezar Thanks again)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using vanilla js (strictly since you didnt use the `jquery` tag in your question) with working snippet:

```js
function doAction() {
  var messageObj = {
    text: "Here is some text"
  }

  document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerText = messageObj.text;
}
```

```html
<span>PLACEHOLDER</span>
<button onclick="doAction()">do</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with using tag name.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('span').textContent(message.text);
```

OR can assign some class or id to the span

```
<span id="my_id"></span>

document.getElementById('my_id').textContent(message.text);


<span class="my_id"></span>

document.getElementsByClassName('my_id')[0].textContent(message.text);
```

Using jQuery,you can do like this

```
$(".my_id").text(message.text)

OR

$("#my_id").text(message.text)
```

Comment: There is no `getElementByTagName` in JavaScript. You probably made a typo and meant `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: @cezar Thanks.Its typo

Answer (score 0):

If you're using plain HTML and vanilla JavaScript, then why should something else but `message.text` appear within the span tags.

Using just plain JavaScript you could do something like:

```
var message = {
    text: "Here is some text"
};
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var el = spans[0];
el.innerText = message.text;
```

Here is a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/k1q9jo5n/