# ReactJS how to render an HTML object span element within a string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How can I convert an HTML object containing a span element within a string into something that Reactjs can actually render as HTML?

To clarify, here's what I have:

```
let myObject = "apple tree"
```

I wrote a function that wraps the word apple in a span tag (html object)

```
<span style="color: red;">apple</span>tree
```

my website is displaying:

```
[object Object] tree
```

BUT it should be displaying

```
apple tree
```

where "apple" is colored red because it is wrapped in a span

I'm passing the string into my component like this:

```
return (<div>{myObject}</div>)
```

Not sure how to render this object as actual HTML element, and not sure if I doing dangerouslySetInnerHTML is the best and only option here too

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
{<span style="color: red;">{'apple'}</span>tree}
```

Lemme know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render an HTML object it's just

```
let myObject=<span style="color: red;">apple</span>;
return (<div>{myObject} tree</div>);
```

if you are doing something like this `return (<div>{this.getRedApple()} tree</div>);` then in your `getRedApple()` function you should just return the variable like so:

```
let myObject=<span style="color: red;">apple</span>;
return (myObject);
```

Don't have it like this: `return ({myObject})`

Answer (score 0):

Create component for it

```
class Apple extends Component {
          render() {
            return <span color={this.props.style.color} >{this.props.strApple}</span>tree;
          }
        }
```

use that component;

```
  const style = { color: 'red' };
  const element = <Apple strApple="apple tree" style="style "/>;
```

And render it

```
ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This Question is already answered here.
[Insert value of object into span tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478114/insert-value-of-object-into-span-tag)

Referring to answer of Nitin Dhomse, you can do something like this:

```
let myObject = "apple tree";
<span id="span" style="color: red"></span>
$("#span").text(myObject);
```

This will give you the required output.

Comment: Probably want to use a React specific solution for a question with a `reactjs` tag. jQuery and React aren't really designed to play together. Sure, there's [instructions on adding a jQuery plugin to a React app](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html#how-to-approach-the-problem), but those gymnastics aren't required here imo.