# Replace tag text everytime button is pressed

Tags: javascript, dom

```html
<html>
<title>Self4You</title>
<body bgcolor="yellow">
<center>
<img width="250px" src=http://self4you.pt/assets/img/678.png></img>
<h1 style="font-family:verdana;">
Tire a sua Senha.
</h1>

<a id="ticket" href="com.fidelier.printfromweb://$intro$$bighw$    Self4You$intro$$small$            Sua Vez: $intro$$bighw$       >counter<  $intro$$intro$$intro$$intro$">

<input type="image" src="http://bsccongress.com/im6/white-circle-button-clip-art.png">

</a>


</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to change the content of the tag "ticket"?
I want to replace ">counter<" with a number everytime i click the image.
i'll apreciate any help.
thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible. What specifically are you having problems with? There are multiple steps involved, each of which have been discussed extensively on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm starting to learn javascript and i just don't have a clue on how to do it.

Comment: Your HTML code is invalid. do you want to change the word insid `href`?? `<a id="ticket" href="com.fidelier.printfromweb://$intro$$bighw$    Self4You$intro$$small$Sua Vez: $intro$$bighw$>counter<$intro$$intro$$intro$$intro$"> input... </a>`

Comment: Look at [how to bind an event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [how to change the content of an element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1358810/218196). I found both by searching for `javascript bind click event handler` and `javascript change element content` on Google btw.

Comment: i want to change text inside the tag <tag here>...</tag>, not <tag> here</tag>

Comment: That called attribute of tag... please try to correct your HTML code first.