# Change innerHTML of span

Tags: javascript, html

I am wanting to change the innerHTML of a span however I am having some issues.

Part of code I need to edit

```
<li class="mdl-step mdl-step--editable is-active">
                <span class="mdl-step__label">
                <span class="mdl-step__title">
                    <span class="mdl-step__title-text">Your Information</span>
                    <span class="mdl-step__title-message">Edit this step later</span>
                </span>
                    <span class="mdl-step__label-indicator"><span class="mdl-step__label-indicator-content">1</span>
                </span>
                </span>
                <div class="mdl-step__content">
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-step__actions">
                  <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-button--raised" data-stepper-next>
                        Continue
                      </button>
                  <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-stepper-cancel>
                        Cancel
                      </button>
                </div>
              </li>
```

I need to change

```
<span class="mdl-step__label-indicator"><span class="mdl-step__label-indicator-content">1</span>
                    </span>
                    </span>
```

to

```
 <span class="mdl-step__label-indicator">
<i class="material-icons mdl-step__label-indicator-content">check</i>
                        </span>
```

Javascript code ( but I made it even easier for you)

```
elements = steps[e].querySelectorAll("span.mdl-step__label > span.mdl-step__label-indicator");
                        alert(elements[0].innerHTML+" this better work");

                        elements[0].appendChild( document.createTextNode('<i class="material-icons mdl-step__label-indicator-content">check</i>') );
```

also tried

```
 var span = document.getElementByClass('li.is-active >  span.mdl-step__label-indicator");
       text = document.createTextNode("44546465");
        span.innerHTML = ''; // clear existing
        span.appendChild(text);
```

None of them worked.

Full HTML code

```
 <section class="mdl-stepper">

    <div class="mdl-grid">
      <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
       <!-- markup -->
        <ul class="mdl-stepper mdl-stepper--linear mdl-stepper--horizontal" id="ipet-stepper">
          <li class="mdl-step mdl-step--editable is-active">
            <span class="mdl-step__label">
            <span class="mdl-step__title">
                <span class="mdl-step__title-text">Your Information</span>
                <span class="mdl-step__title-message">Edit this step later</span>
            </span>
                <span class="mdl-step__label-indicator"><span class="mdl-step__label-indicator-content">1</span>
            </span>
            </span>
            <div class="mdl-step__content">
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-step__actions">
              <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-button--raised" data-stepper-next>
                    Continue
                  </button>
              <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-stepper-cancel>
                    Cancel
                  </button>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mdl-step">
            <span class="mdl-step__label">
            <span class="mdl-step__title">
                <span class="mdl-step__title-text">Your Pets</span>
            </span>
                <span class="mdl-step__label-indicator"><span class="mdl-step__label-indicator-content">2</span>
            </span>
            </span>
            <div class="mdl-step__content"></div>
            <div class="mdl-step__actions">
              <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-button--raised" data-stepper-next>
                    Continue
                  </button>
              <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-stepper-cancel>
                    Cancel
                  </button>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mdl-step">
            <span class="mdl-step__label">
            <span class="mdl-step__title">
                <span class="mdl-step__title-text">Emergency Contacts</span>
                <span class="mdl-step__title-message">Who should we contact if your pet goes missing?</span>
            </span>
                <span class="mdl-step__label-indicator"><span class="mdl-step__label-indicator-content">3</span>
            </span>
            </span>
            <div class="mdl-step__content"></div>
            <div class="mdl-step__actions">
              <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-button--raised" data-stepper-next>
                    Continue
                  </button>
              <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-stepper-cancel>
                    Cancel
                  </button>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: what is `steps[e]`

Comment: have you tried `document.getElementByClass("mdl-step__label-indicator-content").innerHTML = VALUE`

Comment: @RusselHarrower can you check your posted javascript code. There is a quotation error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the text of a span element in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-in-javascript)

Comment: Check your HTML nesting as it appears that you have one span too many. Looat the lines with </span></span>

Comment: Are you wanting to change all those elements that match the query selector or just the one with 1 in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of code to digest here. I'm not sure where to start, but some issues leap out:

```
document.createTextNode(
    '<i class="material-icons mdl-step__label-indicator-content">check</i>')
```

You cannot create a text node that contains HTML, instead do:

```
var i = document.createElement('i');
i.style.className = 'material-icons mdl-step__label-indicator-content';
var text = document.createTextNode('check');
i.appendChild(text);

elements[0].appendChild(i);
```

Alternatively (and slower) use `innerHTML` directly:

```
elements[0].innerHTML = 
    '<i class="material-icons mdl-step__label-indicator-content">check</i>';
```

However, that does clear the existing content (slowly). If you want to clear it quickly use:

```
var span = elements[0];
while (span.firstChild)
    span.removeChild(span.firstChild);
```

If you only want the first element try:

```
// Replace
elements = steps[e].querySelectorAll(
    'span.mdl-step__label > span.mdl-step__label-indicator');

// With
element = steps[e].querySelector(
    'span.mdl-step__label > span.mdl-step__label-indicator');
```

Next up, your nesting could be off and it really doesn't add much to the query's performance, so try:

```
element = steps[e].querySelector(
    '.mdl-step__label .mdl-step__label-indicator');

// Or even
element = steps[e].querySelector('.mdl-step__label-indicator');
```

Unless you're doing this multiple times in a single frame the `innerHTML` call is going to be much slower than this.

Comment: the only part i am not getting is wihle (span.firstChild)
    span.removeChild(span.firstChild);

rest works well

Comment: @RussellHarrower That's the quickest way to empty a node in the DOM. Setting `innerHTML` is fairly slow, even if you're setting it to an empty string. Mostly the performance difference doesn't really matter, but if you're trying to keep frame rates high and DOM changes smooth it's a useful trick.

Comment: but where is the span variable like how does it know which span

Comment: @RussellHarrower ah, I've updated the answer to clarify, `span` is just the name of the DOM element variable that you want to empty.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `appendChild`, use `innerHTML` to replace all content in that span,

```
elements[0].innerHTML = '<i class="material-icons mdl-step__label-indicator-content">check</i>' ;
```

If you still want to use `appendChild` then you can't simply the markup that like that. You need to create element using `document.createElement` and then use need to use `appendChild` to insert new created element.

**Using AppendChild**

Not sure what `steps[e]` is, so I'm using `document` instead

```
elements = document.querySelectorAll("span.mdl-step__label > span.mdl-step__label-indicator");
alert(elements[0].innerHTML+" this better work");

var iTag = document.createElement('i');
iTag.setAttribute('class', 'material-icons mdl-step__label-indicator-content');
iTag.innerHTML = 'check';

elements[0].appendChild(iTag) ;
```

Note: This will not replace everything. It will just update the `span` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
While your span contain only one child span and you want to remove it so use empty function then use append to add the <i> tag

$(".mdl-step__label-indicator").empty();
$(".mdl-step__label-indicator").append('<i class="material-icons mdl-step__label-indicator-content">check</i>');
```