# I am trying to make a constantly updating span have a formatted number

Tags: javascript, html

```
$<span id="money">0</span>
```

I have this span in my html document that is linked to my javascript.

```
function formatNumber(e){
  var rex = /(^\d{2})|(\d{1,3})(?=\d{1,3}|$)/g,
  val = this.textContent.replace(/^0+|\.|,|\s/g,"")
  res;

  if (val.length) {
    res = Array.prototype.reduce.call(val, (p,c) => c + p)        // reverse the pure numbers string
           .match(rex)                                            // get groups in array
           .reduce((p,c,i) => i - 1 ? p + "," + c : p + "." + c); // insert (.) and (,) accordingly
    res += /\.|,/.test(res) ? "" : ".0";                          // test if res has (.) or (,) in it
    this.value = Array.prototype.reduce.call(res, (p,c) => c + p);// reverse the string and display
  }
}

var mySpan = document.getElementById("money"); 
mySpan.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", formatNumber);
```

The code above is the function. I have to try and format the span displaying "money" into a number separated by commas every time the span is updated, for example 1234 would become 1,234 and so on. However the code does not appear to be working as expected and the number remains unformatted.

Comment: Why don't you just use [Number.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) instead of that.... complicated mess?

Comment: I tried that originally but encountered the same problem of it not updating

Comment: Yes, because `span` elements don't have a `value` attribute.

Comment: Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the text of a span element in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-in-javascript)

Comment: No, there's no way around that.  You can, though, set the text using the same attribute you used to retrieve the text....

Comment: I still don't seem to be having any luck getting this to work

Answer (score 0):

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tx4n2cwo/2/). The funcation at work being

```
function format(){
  var dollars = document.getElementsByClassName('money');
  for(var i = 0; i < dollars.length; i++){
      dollars[i].innerHTML = dollars[i].innerHTML.replace(/(\d{1,3})(?=\d{3})/g, '$1,');
  }
}
```

What I'm doing is pulling all elements with the class name "money", then reassigning their innerhtml to a regexed version of itself. The regex being

```
/(\d{1,3})(?=\d{3})/g
    (/d{1,3}) //Find a group of digits between 1 and 3 digits in length. assigned to $1
    (?= //Look ahead
       \d{3} //Look for exactly 3 digits
    )
/g //repeat until no more matches are found
```

Then, just insert a comma after `$1` Note that this does not work for decimals greater than 3 digits, but money should never reach thousandths anyways.