# getting html user generated input is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a quantity selector where user click on plus or minus to increase or decrease the number.

```js
function initQuantity() {
  if ($('.plus').length && $('.minus').length) {
    var plus = $('.plus');
    var minus = $('.minus');
    var value = $('#quantity_value');

    plus.on('click', function() {
      var x = parseInt(value.text());
      value.text(x + 1);
    });

    minus.on('click', function() {
      var x = parseInt(value.text());
      if (x > 1) {
        value.text(x - 1);
      }
    });
  }
}

initQuantity();
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Quantity:</span>
<div class="quantity_selector">
  <span class="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  <span id="quantity_value">1</span>
  <span class="plus"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>
```

Everything works fine. I need to do two things; set a maximum for `quantity_value` and get the user value. I tried this for getting the user value

```
var qty = document.getElementById("quantity_value").value;
```

but what i get is:

> undefined

How can I implement getting the user-incremented value and setting the maximum for the quantity selector?

Comment: span doesn't have 'value' property, use textContent.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DanielGale/joq9gm5q/2/
You shouldn't need parseInt if you are controlling the number in the span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the quantity_value in

```
var x = parseInt(value.text());
```

You can apply your validation before the update

```
value.text(x + 1);
```

Like this

```
if(x <= MAXIMUM_VALUE){
    value.text(x + 1);
}
```

Comment: Agreed, nice catch. No need to fetch it from the HTML again. In fact, I might define the variable as "1" and insert it into the HTML in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It is returning undefined because span elements don't have the value property you are trying to access. The following should work in modern browsers...

```
var qty = document.getElementById("quantity_value").textContent;
```

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-in-javascript)

Comment: or, as they're using jQuery elsewhere, `$("#quantity_value").text();`

Answer (score 1):

You are already using jQuery so take advantage of it instead of using `document.getElementById("quantity_value")` you can use a jQuery selector.

Also as @sinisake pointed out you must access the text content, not the value as `span` elements don't have a value attribute:

```
var qty = $('#quantity_value').text();
```