# JavaScript span.appendChild() Returns Uncaught TypeError From Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tampermonkey

I'm sort of a novice with HTML and JavaScript, but I'm running into some trouble with this one.

I have the following code snippet:

```
<div data-contents="true">

    <div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="369vc" data-offset-key="e371k-0-0">

        <div data-offset-key="e371k-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj">

            <span data-offset-key="e371k-0-0">

                <span data-text="true">TEXT HERE</span>

            </span>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I'm trying to insert text where the "TEXT HERE" resides using the following commands (as found on [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-in-javascript))) from within the console:

```
span = document.getElementById("data-text");
txt = document.createTextNode("TEXT HERE");
span.appendChild(txt);
```

However, when I run that command, all I get in return is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null at <anonymous>:3:6`.

I've read it's caused by the element not being defined prior to the script running, so it's unable to assign the text to it. I'm not fully clear on why it wouldn't run even though the website has already loaded though. Any ideas? I'm hoping to eventually hook this to a button that's loaded on the webpage, instead of it automatically running upon load if that makes sense.

*NOTE: I'm not creating a website from scratch. This is a script being used on Facebook by TamperMonkey, so I can't permanently load it into the webpage.*

Comment: I don't see anything with the id "data-text" in what you posted. The `.getElementById()` function is for fetching a DOM node by the value of its "id" parameter.

Comment: I read in multiple places that you can use `.getElementByID`  to target the `span` tag

Comment: Yes, you can, but your `<span>` tag does not have an "id" attribute at all.

Answer (score 1):

You call this:

```
span = document.getElementById("data-text");
```

But don't have any id called `data-text`.

Either change the code to this:

```
span = document.querySelector("[data-text]");
```

Or change the html to this:

```
<span id="data-text" data-text="true">TEXT HERE</span>
```

> Notice the `id="data-text"` That is what `getElementById` is looking for.

Comment: Someone is liberally passing out down votes with no reason when both answers are valid and useful. What gives?

Comment: I mean, like, that's just your opinion.

Comment: If no explanation for the down vote is provided then, you are right, it is just *mean*. And we have no way of correcting any possible mistakes in our answer.