# How to fill an html tag with a variable from javascript

Tags: javascript

So, I am trying to to fill an html tag with a variable from javascript. The code that I am doing seems to be partially working but not fully as it is not showing what I am trying to show

The problem is that when I alert the variable from javascript, the value is displayed in the alert, but when calling it from different parts, nothing happens.

```js
var client_code = "SOMETHING";
client_code = String(client_code);
document.getElementById('titleClientCode').value = client_code;

//javasctipt where it is not showing
document.getElementById("titleClientCode").hidden = false;
```

```html
<h4 class="modal-title" style="display:inline" type="hidden" id="titleClientCode" name="titleClientCode"></h4>
```

Comment: Welcome.  Please make a runnable snippet.  See how to create an [mcve]

Comment: `h4` tags do not have a `value`. Only inputs do. They also don't have `type` or `name` attributes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the text of a span element in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are messing up quit a bit here. You have the headline `<h4>` element. If you use the value, you will set the value of this line. The value is not equal to the displayed content (which is the `innerHTML`). I think you want to use the following code

```js
var client_code = "SOMETHING";
document.getElementById("titleClientCode").innerHTML = client_code;
```

```html
<h4 class="modal-title" style="display:inline" id="titleClientCode" name="titleClientCode"></h4>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot, that worked....as I was using the value, and I switched with innerHTML

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
document.getElementById('titleClientCode').value = client_code;
```

with

```
document.getElementById('titleClientCode').innerHTML= client_code;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that totally worked. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

Header tags don't have a `value`. [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp)

What you'll want to use is the `textContent` [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp)

So your finished product would look something like this:

````
<h4 class="modal-title" style="display:inline" type="hidden"  id="titleClientCode" name="titleClientCode"></h4>

<script>
//Javascript Part - works when alerted
var client_code = "SOMETHING";
client_code = String(client_code);
document.getElementById('titleClientCode').textContent = client_code;

//javasctipt where it is not showing
document.getElementById("titleClientCode").hidden = false;
</script>```
````

Answer (score 2):

Only `input`s have a `value`.

To change / set the content of other elements, use either `innerText`, `innerHTML`, or `textContent`.

I used `innerText` for this answer:

```js
//Html Part


//Javascript Part - works when alerted
var client_code = "SOMETHING";
client_code = String(client_code);
document.getElementById('titleClientCode').innerText = client_code;

//javasctipt where it is not showing
document.getElementById("titleClientCode").hidden = false;
```

```html
<h4 class="modal-title" style="display:inline" type="hidden"  id="titleClientCode" name="titleClientCode"></h4>
```