# how can I add a text file into javascript then into html? (Display text in html from javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put a text file into a javascript function and then somehow display that function in the html.

The javascript can't be inside the html file; it has to be referenced from outside the file like a:

Here is a picture of what I am trying to do (I don't have enough rep points):

https://i.ibb.co/xGxw1bm/1.png

I have tried:

1. I tried using "XMLHttpRequest" to try and display the text file in the front end html by uploading my text file to dropbox so I can be using the "https" method to communicated instead of "file://" since that doesn't work in the twitch developer rig

```
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='  https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://app.box.com/s/zkt7pbsv0cnnogafcxq8n5elmc9plxbz';
\\later in the code; because I didn't know where to put the rest of the http commands so I put them in the twitch.onAuthorized function which needs to be ran in this script anyway. I don't know what it does but it needs to be there and since its already a function I figured it would be better there. (Unless someone can make a function where all the https stuff is in one function.)

twitch.onAuthorized(function (auth) {
  // save our credentials
  token = auth.token;
  tuid = auth.userId;

Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
console.log(Http.responseText);
  setAuth(token);
  $.ajax(requests.get)
}
});
```

2. I tried the document.getelement thingy but that doesn't ever explain to me how to put this in the html as text:
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML

Everything I have seen on this has always said you can manipulate using a  tag but I have not seen one example where this document.get thingy is in another javascript file and they have to reference it to the html. I always see it in the same file with the html.

What function can I use to extract that function into the html file without using a button? I just want it to display on like an object tag or an iframe tag.

3. I tried using the object tag....
   It seems to work however......
   I notice it pulls the website like an html file. Is there anyway to direct link a text file to the object tag but just the text data shows? Do I have to upload my text to a secure https? Can I even pull a text file from the web without it pulling in the html?

Here is the html file exact: (Note: This is testing, so none of the words matter in the html file. I am just trying to learn how to put text on here from another javascript file or backend.js javascript file. What tag or reference can I use to put a function from javascript into here without a button? Just on the screen I need the text.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Viewer Page</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
    <div id="app" class="full-height"></div>
    <script src="twitch-ext.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="viewer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <h2>Hello, World!</h2>
    <p>Would you care to cycle a color?</p>
<object type="text/html" data="https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the viwer.js (this is where the javascript for getting the text file needs to be):

```
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='  https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://app.box.com/s/zkt7pbsv0cnnogafcxq8n5elmc9plxbz';

let token = '';
let tuid = '';

const twitch = window.Twitch.ext;

// create the request options for our Twitch API calls
const requests = {
  set: createRequest('POST', 'output'),

};

function createRequest (type, method) {
  return {
    type: type,
    url: location.protocol + '//localhost:8081/musicoutput/' + method,
    success: updateBlock,
    error: logError
  };
}

function setAuth (token) {
  Object.keys(requests).forEach((req) => {
    twitch.rig.log('Setting auth headers');
    requests[req].headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token };
  });
}

twitch.onContext(function (context) {
  twitch.rig.log(context);
});

twitch.onAuthorized(function (auth) {
  // save our credentials
  token = auth.token;
  tuid = auth.userId;

Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
console.log(Http.responseText);
  setAuth(token);
  $.ajax(requests.get)
}
});

function updateBlock (hex) {
  twitch.rig.log('Updating music info');

}

function logError(_, error, status) {
  twitch.rig.log('EBS request returned '+status+' ('+error+')');
}

function logSuccess(hex, status) {
  twitch.rig.log('EBS request returned '+hex+' ('+status+')');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the text of a span element in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-in-javascript)

Comment: Did assigning `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` not work? Not clear what you have tried and what is not working.

Comment: Thank you for replying back @WilliamLohan! I guess I am not sure how to reference the "demo" part back in the html for use. Everytime I see an example of using the ID tag in html, its for a button. I don't know to get the output the document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML into the html if if that phrase is in another javascript file.

Comment: I don't know how to explain this but if there was just 1 example online of this phrase "document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML"
in a javascript file of its own and it being used in another html file. That would be great. Yes i understand you can get the javascript file by using the <script> tag but how can I get the function of "document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML" into the html without using a button but rather, just displaying the text on the html front end?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/zetuqitilo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-how-can-i-add-a-text-file-into-javascript-then-into-html-dis

Comment: I want to give you an upvote for those last two links! How can i do that? And thank you so much William. I know to some, this is there job, for me this is my happiness in my spare time. :)