# How do I access a particular part of an HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, console

I am using console on google chrome to edit the web page. I could just use inspect element and change what I am trying to change, but after discovering I could do this on the console... I wanted to do it that way.

Here is the code of the website as it is now:

Name:Mountain, Rocky

I am trying to replace Mountain, Rocky so it says "Mountain, Appalachia"

So far, I've tried: document.getElementByTagName("li")[12].replaceWith("Name:Mountain, Rocky ");

and lots of other combinations (replacing the quotes inside the replaceWith with &quot, just writing "Name: Mountain, Appalachia&nbsp" and nothing works

most of the time the change I want to make shows up in the "Name:" part and the Mountain, Rocky goes away.

How do I maintain the Name: and the Mountain part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `document.getElementByTagName("li")[12]` is your `<li>` element.
To change inner text of element you can use:

- [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) - `document.getElementByTagName("li")[12].innerText = 'Mountain, Appalachia'`
- [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) - `document.getElementByTagName("li")[12].innerHTML = 'Mountain, Appalachia'`

Similiar questions were answered many times. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-in-javascript)