# Insert text into HTML element with Javascript function return

Tags: javascript

This is a piece of my HTML code:

```
<label for="input_train"><script>mountainTrains("all");</script></label>
```

`mountainTrains()` is a javascript function, which returns string. I want this string to be passed as a text of the label element on the website. This piece of code however only results in an empty string, even if `mountainTrains()` returns non-empty string. Is there anything wrong about the syntax I'm trying to access javascript function from HTML?

Function definition:

```
function mountainTrains(par) {
    if (par !== 'all') {
        return 'One train';
    } else {
        return 'All trains';
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the function definition? Without providing a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, it is hard for anyone to help troubleshoot this without guessing. From what is shown guesses would require us asking far too many questions to get to the root

Comment: Added function definition.

Comment: Additionally it is not good practice to add a script tag inside another one

Comment: You should combine all your script tags in one place, or even decouple them from the HTML code (in other words add them to another file).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the text of a span element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

To edit HTML with JS, don't put the script tag inside the element you're trying to edit. Instead do something like this:

```js
function mountainTrains(par) {
  if (par !== 'all') {
    return 'One train';
  } else {
    return 'All trains';
  }
}
document.getElementById("my_label").innerHTML = mountainTrains("all");
```

```html
<label for="input_train" id="my_label"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to modify the text content of the label element like the following way:

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  
    document.querySelector('label[for=input_train]').textContent = mountainTrains("all");
    
    function mountainTrains(par) {
      if (par !== 'all') {
        return 'One train';
      } else {
        return 'All trains';
      }
    }
    
  });
</script>

<label for="input_train"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to make this work by simply placing the function call inside the element and not passing in any element identifiers is to use `document.currentScript` and then setting the text of the `parentNode`.

Note this is not commonly done. I'm just pointing out how it can be done.

I would not pursue this very far as there more robust approaches depending on your use case that don't require individual script tags for each call

```css
label{  padding: 1em; border:1px solid grey}
```

```html
<script>
function mountainTrains(par) {
    let txt = par === 'all' ? 'All trains' : 'One train';
    document.currentScript.parentNode.textContent = txt
}
</script>

<label for="input_train"><script>mountainTrains("all");</script></label>
<label for="another_train"><script>mountainTrains("one");</script></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use JavaScript for [DOM manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)
I would not recommend to insert the **script** tag in the **label** itself. The best practice is to put it right before the closing tag of the **body** element, more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp)

also the function to add this text insde the lable should look something like this

```js
  document.getElementsByClassName("random_class_name")[0].innerHTML = 'the text for the label'
```

```html
<label class="random_class_name" for="input_train"></label>
<input name="input_train" type="text">
```

Note that we are referring to *document.getElementsByClassName("random_class_name")**[0]*** it is because getElementsByClassName function returns all elements that have such a class name so if there are 10 of them you can refference them like you would an array. This particular one is called a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="input_train" onclick="event.target.innerText = mountainTrains('all');">text</label>

  
  <script>
  
    
    function mountainTrains(par) {
    if (par !== 'all') {
        return 'One train';
    } else {
        return 'All trains';
    }
}
    
  </script>
```