# How to make an HTML header (<h1>) change with a var prompt at webage load?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a simple calculator that calculates income made, income spent on food, housing, etc. I want to make the header change to: Budget analysis for "Name Here"
Using:

```
var Name=prompt("Enter Your Name.","Name")
```

How would I do this

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-using-javascript

Comment: The proposed answers do not fully answer question OP. Since the OP also needs to show a method for concatenating a static string with a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  var Name = prompt("Enter Your Name.","Name");
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = Name;
})
```

```html
<h1>Budget analysis for <span id="name"></span></h1>
```