# assigning "let" variable to element's innerText

Tags: javascript, html

I am begginer at JS and I want to change the innerText of HTML element.

This works:

```js
let span = document.querySelector('span');

span.innerText = 20;
```

```html
<span></span>
```

And this does not work:

```js
let span = document.querySelector('span');

let element = span.innerText;

element = 20;
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1358815/571723

Comment: You're just copying the text to the variable. The variable is not an alias for the `span.innerText` expression.

Comment: @dmikester1 He already knows how to do that, he did it in the first snippet.

Comment: It's the same reason that `a=1; b=a; b=2;` doesn't change `a`.