# How to display dynamic variable in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering how to display a number in HTML that was created dynamically later on in the code. For instance I initialize the value `reportDataLength` in `data()`, and I tested that it was returning the right value by doing a `console.log()`, but now I want to display this value in HTML?

```
  name: 'notification-tray',
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Notifications',
          value: 'Body',
          width: '380px',
        },
      ],
      reportData: [],
      reportDataLength: 0,
    };
  },
  async created() {
    await this.getReportDataLength();
  },
  methods: {
    async getReportDataLength() {
      ... this.reportDataLength = this.reportData.length;
      
      console.log(this.reportDataLength);
    },
  },
};
```

But obviously when I do something like this,

```
      <span class="d-none">Notification Button</span>
      <span class="badge">this.reportDataLength</span>
```

it doesn't work correctly. The other solutions I saw for similar problems used JQuery, and I feel like there's a simple way to reference this, but I can't seem to find it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the text of a span element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay so if you are using pure Javascript , u can use this in your javascript function :

```
Document.getElementsByClassName('badge').innerHtml=this.reportDataLength ;
```

otherwise if you are using vue js you can try something like this in your html file :

```
      <span class="badge">{{reportDataLength}}</span>
```

Comment: awesome! I am using VueJs so `<span class="badge">{{reportDataLength}}</span>` that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can do `document.getElementById("ID-HERE").innerHTML = "new stuff"`, but be warned that setting `innerHTML` is dangerous.