# how to I change <h2> tag with Javascript or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to change the text in the h2 inside a class using css or javascript? I think it is possible through JS but not sure how.

Please note that I cannot change span or give id. Also, I have multiple sections that uses the same div class "twocol-box1 superflex-content-6-12" but only one section with the H2 text "old text".

Here is what I have

```
<div class="twocol-box1 superflex-content-6-12">
  <h2>old text</h2>
```

Comment: That isn't valid HTML.

Comment: I have updated HTML. Please check.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the text of a span element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If There is only one div with class `twocol-box1 superflex-content-6-12` who has h2 as child**

```js
document.querySelector("div.twocol-box1.superflex-content-6-12 h2").innerText = "New Value"
```

**If Not U can use [nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)**

```js
document.querySelector("div.twocol-box1.superflex-content-6-12:nth-child(<That Div Position>) h2").innerText = "New Value"
```

for example
if you want select the 2nd div then

```
document.querySelector("div.twocol-box1.superflex-content-6-12:nth-child(2) h2")
```

Comment: I have multiple div class. I tried this and it doesn't work. Am I missing something? I dunno much JS, so its possible I am missing something. <script>
document.querySelector("div.twocol-box1.superflex-content-6-12:nth-child(2) h2").innerText = "ABC"
</script>
Maybe a quote or something?

Comment: make sure in nth-child div position rank is correct, and then if it still doesn't work, can you upload code to codepen and share the link

Answer (score 6):

You can access the h2 inside a div whose class is "twocol-box1 superflex-content-6-12" by using javascript "querySelector" method :

```
const h2Tag = document.querySelector("twocol-box1 superflex-content-6-12 > h2");
```

Note that querySelector method acts like a CSS selector.

Then, the content of an element can be changed using the "innerHTML" property :

```
h2Tag.innerHTML = 'New text';
```

Comment: Is this how I add this? <script>
const h2Tag = document.querySelector("twocol-box1 superflex-content-6-12 > h2");
h2Tag.innerHTML = 'New text';

</script> Please note that I have mutiple places on the page that uses this div class. Thanks

Comment: This will change the text everywhere you wrote an h2 iniside a tag with the "twocol-box1 superflex-content-6-12" class (as a direct child) as soon as the script will load

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
var elem = document.querySelector("div.twocol-box1.superflex-content-6-12 h2");
elem.innerHTML = "new text"
```

You select the "h2" Tag in a div with the classes twocol-box1 and  superflex-content-6-12 and change the Text with innerHTML method