# How to use getElementById in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

How show the content **let text: string** in tag

using typescript and getElementById?

**Code index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Exercice typescript</h1>
    <p id="text">Text: </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code index.ts**

```
let text: string = 'Exercice typescript';
let textAuth = document.getElementById("text") as HTMLElement | null
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the text of a span element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Because the element might be `null`, you need to first perform a conditional check to ensure that it exists before updating its text content. If you want to *append* to the text content, you also must check to be sure that the presumed text content exists:

> See also [`Node.textContent` - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/DYUwLgBGIB6QvBA5AURiATgYwJZZFAJ4AOIAzlhjsWEgNwBQok0cAggK5gAWEiAJgHssHALYgAdmAB0Ac3ApQ4qQCFCASX4AKJK1oBKRjgBmELXs48A-NL0BhQVMlh9UWGEvdb7h06l83OEYgA)

```js
let text = 'Exercice typescript';
let textAuth = document.getElementById('text');
if (textAuth?.textContent) textAuth.textContent += text;
```

```html
<h1>Exercice typescript</h1>
<p id="text">Text: </p>
```