# unable to change content of duplicated modal card

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/media/media.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/hover/hover.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
      <!-- DISCOVER -->
      <section class="services-section">
        <div class="services-overview">
            <h4>
                <a class="discover" href="#">
                    discover
                </a>
            </h4>
            <h3>
                <a class="hot-services" href="#">
                    our hot services
                </a>
            </h3>
            <p>
                <a class="overview" href="#">
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of 
                    the printing and typesetting industry. 
                    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- TRAVEL OPTIONS -->
        <div class="travel-options-main-cont">
            <!-- container1 -->
            <div class="booking-container">
                <div class="airplane">
                    <img class="modalBtn" src="/images/travel photos/airplane.png" alt="airplane">
                </div>
                <div class="modal" >
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <img src="/images/travel photos/airplane.png" alt="airplane">
                        <h3>
                            <a class="modal-title" href="#">
                               <h3>
                        <a class="modal-title" href="#">
                            flight booking
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                    <p>
                        <a class="modal-text" href="#">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
                        printing and typesetting industry. Lorem.
                    </a>
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- container 2 -->
            <div class="booking-container">
                <div class="airplane">
                    <img class="modalBtn"  src="/images/travel photos/airplane.png" alt="airplane">
                </div>
                <div class="modal" >
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <img src="/images/travel photos/airplane.png" alt="airplane">
                        <h3>
                            <a class="modal-title" href="#">
                                hotel and resort booking
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                    <p>
                        <a class="modal-text" href="#">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
                        printing and typesetting industry. Lorem.
                    </a>
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- container3 -->
            <div class="booking-container">
                <div class="airplane">
                    <img class="modalBtn"  src="/images/travel photos/airplane.png" alt="airplane">
                </div>
                <div class="modal" >
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <img src="/images/travel photos/airplane.png" alt="airplane">
                        <h3>
                            <a class="modal-title" href="#">
                                flight booking
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                    <p>
                        <a class="modal-text" href="#">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
                        printing and typesetting industry. Lorem.
                    </a>
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- container4 -->
            <div class="booking-container">
                <div class="airplane">
                    <img class="modalBtn"  src="/images/travel photos/airplane.png" alt="airplane">
                </div>
                <div class="modal" >
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <img src="/images/travel photos/airplane.png" alt="airplane">
                        <h3>
                            <a class="modal-title" href="#">
                                flight booking
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                    <p>
                        <a class="modal-text" href="#">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
                        printing and typesetting industry. Lorem.
                    </a>
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- container5 -->
            <div class="booking-container">
                <div class="airplane">
                    <img class="modalBtn" src="/images/travel photos/airplane.png" alt="airplane">
                </div>
                <div class="modal" >
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <img src="/images/travel photos/airplane.png" alt="airplane">
                    <p>
                        <a class="modal-text" href="#">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
                        printing and typesetting industry. Lorem.
                    </a>
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- container 6 -->
            <div class="booking-container">
                <div class="airplane">
                    <img class="modalBtn" src="/images/travel photos/airplane.png" alt="airplane">
                </div>
                <div class="modal" >
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <img src="/images/travel photos/airplane.png" alt="airplane">
                        <h3>
                            <a class="modal-title" href="#">
                                flight booking
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                    <p>
                        <a class="modal-text" href="#">
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 
                            printing and typesetting industry. Lorem.
                    </a>
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--  -->
        </div>
      </section>
```

```
<script src="app.js/main.js"></script>
```

```
I've duplicated six modal cards that operate OK with javascript, but they are all identical and I can't change different html content. I spent the entire day trying to solve this problem while feeling panicked. I have a deadline until Monday and other tasks to complete, so if I don't succeed here, I won't obtain my first internship. Please assist

Comment: const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const modalBtn = document.querySelector('.modalBtn');
modalBtn.addEventListener('click', showModal);
modal.addEventListener('click', removeModal)
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if ( event.target.classList.contains( 'modalBtn' ) ) {
    showModal(); }
  if ( event.target.classList.contains( 'modal' ) ) {
    removeModal(); }
}, false);
function showModal() {
  document.querySelector('.modal').style.display = "block";
}

function removeModal() {
  document.querySelector('.modal').style.display = "none";
}

Comment: Content of which part you want to get it changed ? Any two three? If not then which particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***No need to get panic. It is a part of life as your are going to start your journey. Keep yourself calm and motivated. Things will get better with time.***

As per my understanding the question, you want to change the content of duplicated card which have the same classes name. If it is the case, you can achieve as follows

```
const bkContEle = document.querySelectorAll('.booking-container'); // Get all container in an array

const getPEle = bkContEle[2].getElementsByClassName('modal-text')[0].innerHTML; // Get innerHTML text of a 2nd booking container

console.log(getPEle);

// Set New content of 3rd Booking Container
const setPEle = bkContEle[2].getElementsByClassName('modal-text')[0].textContent = "I have changed the context of this particular booking container.";

console.log(setPEle);
```

If you want to change text of all cards at once with same text then you can perform iterations over **bkContEle** collection. For some selective you can do as i did or also through iteration with conditional checks based on the index of collection elements.

In above solution, using innerHTML is SO **NOT RECOMMENDED**. Instead, you should create a textNode. This way, you are "binding" your text and you are not, at least in this case, vulnerable to an XSS attack. More detailed answer can be found here [How do I change the text of a span element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358810/how-do-i-change-the-text-of-a-span-element-using-javascript).

The right way to do is as follows:

```
const getTextEle = bkContEle[3].getElementsByClassName('modal-text')[0];

const txt = document.createTextNode("Changin text even a more secure way to protect from XSS attacks");

getTextEle.replaceWith(txt);
```

I hope, it gonna help you out to solve your problem.